# Need help wrapping my object

Tags: modeling, uv, image, uv-image-editor, color

So I've been working on a project and I'm trying to wrap my object with a camo color but for some reason the camo wrap is looks glitchy. Here's a photo, can someone tell me what I've done wrong. [image]

Comment: Change tris to quads and then unwrap.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's because of wrong or no UV mapping.
try to select the parts where you want your texture to be in edit mode, then press **"U"** and **"Smart UV Project"**.

Otherwise you need to place some **seams** around the edges like this:
[image]

In edit mode select the edges you want and press **"U"** and **"mark seam"** after you done with placeing your seams select everything and **"U" - "unwrap"**.

In the UV-editor it should look like this and your texture will be fine.
[image]